# autocomplete combobox extjs with remote ajax store

Tags: ajax, extjs, autocomplete, combobox

I want to add a combobox in my app with a remote store. I have a store that call a php script that returns data in json format and I linked it with my combobox.
The store is autoLoaded but my combobox is still empty.
Here's my store

```
// Define autocomplete model
Ext.define('modelloAC', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'telaio' }
    ]
});
// store auto complete
var autoCompleteStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: modelloAC,
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'script/request.php?operazione=gettelai',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'telai',
            totalProperty: 'results'
        }
    }
});
```

My PHP return a JSON array:

```
{"results":207,"telai":[{"telaio":"ZAR93200001271042"},{"telaio":"ZLA84000001738127"},{"telaio":"VF3WC9HXC33751301"},{"telaio":"W0L0AHL3555247737"}]}
```

My combobox:

```
    xtype: 'combo',
    name: 'telaio',
   //hideTrigger: true,
   store: autoCompleteStore,
   typeAhead: true,
   queryMode: 'remote',
   fieldLabel: 'Telaio'
```

My store loads perfectly but my combobox is empty, where's the problem?

Comment: You should add displayField: 'telaio', to your combobox config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add displayField and valueField in combo config:

```
...
displayField: 'telaio',
valueField: 'telaio',
...
```

Also model in your store is undefined now. Write it as a string:

```
...
model: 'modelloAC',
...
```