# populate extjs combobox from ajax response values

Tags: ajax, extjs, combobox

I have an ajax with the following response and I don't seem to find the way to populate an extjs combobox with the values 1-5.

My response is  :

```
{"items":[{"field":null,"message":null,"value["value1","value2","value3","value4","value5"],"error":false}]}
```

I read that I should use displayField and valueField but in this case I don't know how. I just have a simple array of strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [autocomplete combobox extjs with remote ajax store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301198/autocomplete-combobox-extjs-with-remote-ajax-store)

Answer (score 1):

you need to create store with that strings and bind it to combobox

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'page.php',
    params: {
        id: 1
    },
    success: function(response){
        var data = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
        var storeData = [];
        Ext.each(data.items[0].value,function(v){
            storeData.push({value:v});
        });
        var store  = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
             fields:["value"],
             data:storeData,
             autoLoad: true
         });
        var combobox =  Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
            fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
            store: store,
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'value',
            valueField: 'value'
        });
    }
});
```